# How to verify content present in specific area in a page

Tags: selenium

How do we verify content under a specific area in a page. Let say i need to verify a word in the contentPane. The word may present in span, title or p.

```
<div id="contentPane">
  <span>Something</span>
  <title> Title </>
  <p> Paragraph has actual content </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Selenium 2 (which you should if your situation allows), it is pretty easy.

**C# Code**

```
IWebDriver driver = //whatever browser driver you are using
IWebElement contentPane = driver.FindElement(By.Id("contentPane"));
string text = contentPane.Text;
bool wordPresent = text.Contains("some word");
```

The `Text` property will return the plain-text of all the nested elements so it doesn't matter which specific element (`span`, `title`, or `p`) contained the text.

Comment: will the below statement work??

  assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("//div[@id='contentPane'][contains('New York', 'NY', 'N.Y.')]"));   
                         
IF NOT can you please help to achieve similar in any other way??

Comment: isTextPresent expects a string. I would use the text() XPath function instead of contains().

Comment: i actually want to assert that the contentPane have any of 'New York', 'NY', 'N.Y.' these words.. can anyone please write exact command for this